# Return table if functional dependency is implied to table

Tags: sql

Let R be a (non-empty) relation with attributes a, b and c.

Write a SQL query returning a table containing the single value ’True’ `iff` the functional dependency

`a, b → c` is implied by the table (otherwise the query answer should be empty).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

If functional dependency `(a,b) -> (c)` is implied ie. -

```
a   b   c
--  --  --
20  15  10
20  15  10
```

Query should output something like this:

```
value
-----
True
```

Comment: any sample data and desired output are highly welcome

Comment: @Sergey sorry about that, sample data added-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select 'true' as value where not exists
  (select null from t group by a, b having count(distinct c) > 1)
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_YplOo8G).